# SyntaxError: invalid syntax file.close()

Tags: python

[I keep getting an error here, any help?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwnpD.png)

file = open(FILENAME,'r') is on the same line as file.close with no indentations. Why do I keep getting this error?

Comment: Please post the error message and code in the question itself, not in an image.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to close a parenthesis on this line:

```
ballpark = line.strip*(
```

it should probably be:

```
ballpark = line.strip()
```